# php concatenation parsing errors issue help a newbie

Tags: php

Please help me with this issue. I am trying to echo out 7 or 8 input types.
The input types must have 2 values from my database.

 The Arrays are called : $adressX[] and $adressY. and are automatically loaded when the webpage loads. 
So when number is 0 , i want to create a input type with the value :  ($adressX[0],$adressY[0]).
I keep getting parsing errors , this being my first project on php/javascript.
Please help me. 
My code is like this.

```
<?php  

for ($number=0;$number<=$array_no-1 ;$number++)
{

 echo '<input type="text" id="inputtype"."$number"
                                 value="".$adressX['.$number'],".$adressY['.$number']">';


};
                    ?>
```

Comment: You need an IDE with syntax highlighting. Better yet, learn about [`HEREDOC`](http://php.net/HEREDOC) strings. And look up string syntax in the manual again; if in double quotes, don't break in and out; doesn't aid readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were messing up your quotes and periods. Try this:

```
<?php  
for ($number = 0; $number <= $array_no-1; $number++) {
   echo '<input type="text" id="inputtype' . $number . '" value="' . $adressX[$number] . ',' . $adressY[$number].'" />';
}
?>
```

You should read up on how PHP handles quotes and concatenation, but here are a few examples to get you started.

If you want to start the string with a single quote, you must end/concatenate the string with a single quote as well. Like this:

```
$var = 'yay';
$string = 'The value of the variable is ' . $var;
$string2 = 'The value of the variable is ' . $var . '!'; // Add another string after variable
```

Similarly, if you start with double quotes, you have to end/concatenate with double quotes, like this:

```
$var = "yay";
$string = "The value of the variable is " . $var;
$string2 = "The value of the variable is " . $var . "!";
$string3 = "The value of the variable is $var!";
```

Notice the last example, `$string3`. When using double quotes, you *can* put variables inside the quotes and PHP will still parse them; however, I don't condone this and I ALWAYS concatenate so when using an IDE with syntax highlighting it is obvious where the variables are.

Here is an example of putting the same type quotes in the string that you start/end the string with. To do this, you must use a slash () to tell PHP that these should be parsed as regular quotes instead of delimiters.

```
$string = 'You\'re using escaped quotes now!'; // notice the \ in front of the ' in you're
```

Lastly, here is an example of an HTML string in PHP. I usually start these strings with single quotes so that I can use the conventional double quote delimiters for the HTML.

```
$html = '<div class="someClass">Hello world!</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php  
 for ($number=0;$number<=$array_no-1 ;$number++) {
     echo '<input type="text" id="inputtype'.$number'" value="'.$adressX[$number].','.$adressY[$number].'">';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP's `echo` and `print` statements is usually where new PHP programmers go to for getting output to the screen.  However, when dealing with the output of HTML markup, escaping out of quotes and syntax problems can creep up really quickly.  Instead, try using [`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) to format these more complicated markup elements.  Here's an example.

```
for ( $number = 0; $number <= $array_no - 1; $number++ )
{
    echo sprintf( '<input type="text" id="inputtype%u" value="%s,%s"/>', $number, $addressX[ $number ], $addressY[ $number ] );
}
```

The essential things to know is that, at it's essence, `sprintf` is a complicated kind of search and replace with formatting method.  The first argument is a string with placeholders and all of the following arguments are the variables that will be used in that string to replace the placeholders.  The number of parameters that follow the input string must match the number of placeholders in your string.

You'll notice `%s` and `%u` in the input string that's used in my example.  Those mean format as a `%s` String or as an `%u` Integer.  There are a LOT more ways for format stuff, but, as a novice, these are the ones you'll probably find yourself using the most.

**How is this any easier?**

It's easier because you can us a properly formatted HTML snippet with double quotes and just add in placeholders.  Visually, I find it much more easy to read than a ton of `' . $variable . '` bits scattered throughout your code.

Besides, `sprintf` is going to become something you use regularly as you move up the PHP ladder.  Time to learn it.